# Openconnect on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, libraries

I upgraded my notebook from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Since then, Openconnect stopped working and is giving me the following error message when launching:

> openconnect: error while loading shared libraries: libgnutls.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

All the other libraries seem to be there:

```
ldd $(which openconnect)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff991ef000)
libopenconnect.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopenconnect.so.5 (0x00007f39c815d000)
libgnutls.so.26 => not found
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f39c7da2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f39c79d9000)
libgnutls.so.26 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f39c776f000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f39c7314000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f39c70fa000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f39c6e94000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f39c6c90000)
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f39c68fc000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f39c66d9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f39c63d0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005563d4f55000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f39c61c8000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f39c5faa000)
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f39c44f3000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f39c4171000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f39c3f5a000)
```

It seems like the package is not available in the Ubuntu repositories any more.
There is an Openconnect package though, but how is that supposed to work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to

1. apt purge openconnect
2. apt autoremove (to remove libopenconnect)
3. apt install openconnect

Now openconnect links against the newer (and available) libgnutls30.

Comment: On Arch 5.16.8, updating all packages/package links and reinstalling OpenConnect worked for me. Thanks!